# try/except unittest python exception fails then succeeds

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception

I am trying to use Python try except to retry a function x number of times when an exception occurs. At first I am testing that an exception is captured, and then I want to test that an exception is captured and the call fails but then succeeds and the method returns data as expected. The last part is what I am struggling a little with.

```
        for _ in range(0, NUM_RETRIES):
          try:
              do something()
          except exception as exception:
              if exception:
                  sleep(1)  # wait for 1 second before trying to fetch the data again
              else:
                  break
        return None, None
```

Then this is the test to capture the exception

```
    def test_funct_raises_exception(self, m_get_funct_details, m_logger):
      # Given that the http call fails
      id = "MOCK_ID"
      raised_exception = funct.Exception("unknown error")
      m_get_funct_details.side_effect = raised_exception

      # When
      myFunct()

      # Then
      self.assertEqual(m_get_funct_details.call_count, 5)
      assert m_logger.exception.call_args_list[0][0][
               0] == f"Cannot do this because of the exception"
```

And now I would like to test that the call fails, then retries and succeeds and returns data as expected. But how would I go ahead and implement this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why is a conditional inside the except? if it throws an exception then exception will evaluate True. When is the `else: break` expected to happen?

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Comment: I was using it to capture a specific exception only. To say that if it isn't 'the specific exception' then I do not want to retry and I want to break out of it. Is this wrong? Either way, I am only just trying to find out how to test that say the 2nd retry succeeds and returns data.

Comment: @quamrana thanks, the indentation is correct in my IDE, think it just got a bit messed up when I copied stuff to stackoverflow :)

Comment: Ok, so just keep adjusting the indentation (look at the preview as you are editing) until it looks like it does in your IDE.

Comment: @quamrana cheers! Will keep an eye next time, however, this isn't actually helping me with my question right now so this comment is a little useless, sorry. Understand the good intentions tho :)

Comment: No, keep an eye on it this time please. We literally cannot understand your code while your indentation is incorrect. It will also be nice to see: `def myFunct():` at the top.

Comment: @quamrana done! Hopefully this will be better to read now. Are you able to better help with the actual question now ?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to write a test which mocks `do_something()` and gets the mock to raise exceptions a certain number of times and finally return a value:

```py
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def fail_then_succeed(self, m):
        if m.call_count >= self.max_count:
            return None    # or return data of your choice

        raise self.exception


    # patches here
    def test_something(self, do_sth):
        self.max_count = 2
        self.exception = IndexError   # or exception of your choice

        do_sth.side_effect = lambda: self.fail_then_succeed(do_sth)

        actual = myFunct()

        self.assertEqual(do_sth.call_count, 2)
        self.assertEqual(actual, None)
```

Comment: Many thanks for a solution @quamrana 
I'm running into a few errors in my code when trying to implement this but I think that is for me to figure out. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: That's ok. Just remember, if you come up with a different question then you can ask that on this site.